# how to find iso image according to mounted folder?

Tags: linux, mount

I type `df -h` on linux terminal, and it shows

```
Filesystem    Size   Used    Avail   Use%    Mounted on 

/dev/sr0      3.0G   3.0G    0       100%    /media/SLE-11-SP1-SDK-DVD-x86_64.02.001
```

How can I find the source ISO image which is mounting on `/media/SLE-11-SP1-SDK-DVD-x86_64.02.001`?

Comment: It might depend on how the .iso has been mounted, but you can probable find it by running `losetup -a`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

/dev/sr0 should correspond to a CD/DVD drive. So I assume that you want to create an iso image out of this DVD? If that is the case, you should umount the DVD:

```
sudo umount /media/SLE-11-SP1-SDK-DVD-x86_64.02.001
```

and then create your iso image like this

```
dd if=/dev/sr0 of=~/<whatever_name_u_want>.iso
```

If you actually think an iso image (and not a real DVD) is mounted on your system, try using the `mount` command. (And if you need more help paste its output)